# Hang/freeze on loading/splash screen

Tags: 18.04

I installed Ubuntu, no problem.

I start up my PC and it freezes some time during the loading process, bringing up my cursor. I have no mouse or keyboard control, and I found this out by moving my mouse, as well as using a tutorial that says you can press ctrl+alt+F1 or ctrl+alt+F2 to open terminal.

Not sure of why this is happening. It's my first time ever using Linux, apart from Debian noroot on my phone (which is very limited).

I did manage to access the terminal by hooking in a wired keyboard, and it stops at [OK] Started User Manager for UID 120.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I realized after posting this that my system is x86 and 18.04 is only available in x64. I'm installing 16.04 now. My bad.